# Log4Net, How to get the result of a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, log4net, log4net-appender

I am developing on C# and I was looking for a way to log efficiently on log files and Data Base. I have found Log4Net. My appenders are working fine and I am able to write in my Data Base. I would like to know if it is possible to get the result of a stored procedure through Log4Net.

I explain: I have two appenders ("Add" and "Update") that calls two different stored procedures ("sp_AjouterEntree" and "sp_UpdateEntree" ) on SQLserver. The fist procedure add a line to the table, the second one update this line with an error message (if there is one) and a "EndDate" of the task .

The primary key of the table is an ID. This ID is automatically chosen by the first procedure ("Add").
What I need is to receive the return @@identite of the first procedure to know which line I need to update afterwards in the second appender "Update".

I hope my question is clear enough.
I have looking the answer on other discussion but apparently nobody had this problem before.

Thank you for your help.

The stored procedure (Add Line):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AjouteEntree]
@Flux varchar(50), @Etape varchar(200),@Debut datetime2(7),@Fin datetime2(7),@EtapeKO bit, @Erreur varchar(max) , @Annexe varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN



INSERT INTO [dbo].[Journal]
       ([Jour_Flux]
       ,[Jour_Etape_Flux]
       ,[Jour_Date_Heure_Debut]
       ,[Jour_Date_Heure_Fin]
       ,[Jour_Etape_KO]
       ,[Jour_Erreur]
       ,[Jour_Annexe])
 VALUES
       (@Flux
       ,@Etape
       ,@Debut
       ,@Fin
       ,@EtapeKO
       ,@Erreur
       ,@Annexe)



return @@IDENTITY
END
```

The stored procedure (update Line):

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateEntree]
 @Id integer,@Fin datetime2(7),@EtapeKO bit, @Erreur varchar(max) ,@Annexe varchar(max)
 AS
 BEGIN


UPDATE [dbo].[Journal]
SET [Jour_Date_Heure_Fin] = @Fin
  ,[Jour_Etape_KO] = @EtapeKO
  ,[Jour_Erreur] = @Erreur
  ,[Jour_Annexe] = @Annexe
WHERE [Jour_ID]=@Id


END
```

The first appender:

```
<appender name="Add" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<bufferSize value="1" />
<threshold value="WARN" /> 
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> 
<connectionString value="data source=******************;Database=Test_Log4Net;Trusted_Connection=yes" />

<commandText value="sp_AjouteEntree" />
<commandType value="StoredProcedure"/>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Flux" />
  <dbType value="AnsiString" />
  <size value="50" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{FluxName}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Etape" />
  <dbType value="AnsiString" />
  <size value="500" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%method" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Debut" />
  <dbType value="DateTime" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Fin" />
  <dbType value="DateTime" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@EtapeKO" />
  <dbType value="Byte" />
  <size value="1" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{ErreurKO}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Erreur" />
  <dbType value="AnsiString" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="NULL" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Annexe" />
  <dbType value="AnsiString" />
  <size value="5000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

The second appender:

```
<appender name="Update" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<bufferSize value="1" />

<threshold value="WARN" />

<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

<connectionString value="data source=*****************;Database=Test_Log4Net;Trusted_Connection=yes" />

<commandText value="sp_UpdateEntree" />
<commandType value="StoredProcedure"/>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Id" />
  <dbType value="Int32" />
  <size value="50" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{ID}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Fin" />
  <dbType value="DateTime" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@EtapeKO" />
  <dbType value="Byte" />
  <size value="1" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{ErreurKO}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Erreur" />
  <dbType value="AnsiString" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{messageErreur}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@Annexe" />
  <dbType value="AnsiString" />
  <size value="5000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

Comment: _"What I need is to receive the return @@identity of the first procedure to know which line I need to update afterwards in the second appender "_ Well, you can't, out of the box - the log4net code does not know or care what your stored procedure does or returns. I expect you could do this with a custom appender though.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I think I'm going to try an other log tool.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my stored procedure code

```
USE [JainPort114]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetEventValveONOFF]    Script Date: 17-Apr-17 9:18:14 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEventValveONOFF] 
    --@RTUID int, @StartDatetime datetime, @Enddatetime datetime,
    --@networkId int, @Zoneid int, @BlockId int
    @WhereCondition nvarchar(max) , @StartDatetime nvarchar(100), @Enddatetime nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --If only 1 zone is selected

        begin
            DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
            print @StartDatetime
            print @Enddatetime

            SELECT @SQL = 'select  be.eventdatetime,''Valve Event'' as eventtype, elest.status as ''status'' ,
                r.rtuname, c.channelname,c.channelid, c.tagname, c.tagname as description,
                (select d.Type from DigitalOutput d where  d.DOId = c.typeid and c.subtypeid = 0 and c.EqpTypeId =4) as SensorType,
                --(select Reason from JainPort114_events.dbo.ElementTypeReason where ReasonId = be.Reason and ElementTypeId = 4) as Reason,
                 --(select EleTypeReasonId from JainPort114_events.dbo.ElementTypeReason where ReasonId = be.Reason and ElementTypeId = 4) as ReasonId
                 etr.Reason, etr.ReasonId,
                 case when be.Reason = 8 then (Select be.Errorcode)
                  when be.Reason = 9 then (Select be.Errorcode)
                 else 0
                 end as moidruleid              
                from JainPort114_events.dbo.BSTEvents b, JainPort114_events.dbo.BSTEventsConfig be, rtu r, network n, channel c , JainPort114_events.dbo.ElementTypeReason etr,JainPort114_events.dbo.elementstatus elest
                where be.bsteventid = b.BSTEventsId
                and c.rtuid = r.rtuid
                and r.networkid = n.networkid
                and elest.EleStatusId = be.elestatus
                and be.EventDateTime between '''+ @StartDatetime + ''' and ''' + @Enddatetime + '''
                and b.NetworkId = (select networkno from network  where NetworkId = r.networkid)
                and b.NetworkId = n.networkno
                and JainPort114_events.dbo.HextoDEC(SUBSTRING (be.elenumberandtype, 1, 2), 16) = r.rtuidinnw 
                and JainPort114_events.dbo.HextoDEC(SUBSTRING (be.elenumberandtype, 3, 2), 16) = c.slotidinrtu
                and c.slotidinrtu = be.number
                and etr.ElementTypeId = 4
                and etr.ReasonId =  be.Reason
                    --and n.networkid = @networkId and r.rtuid = @RTUID
                --and  etr.ReasonId = 13
                and r.active =1'
                    +@WhereCondition
                    +'order by be.eventdatetime desc'
                    PRINT @SQL
            EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

        End         
END
```

Comment: “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.”

Comment: If you're sure your code is correct, try to explain it.